# Проблемы с вводом при компиляции в Sublime Text 3

Tags: компиляция, sublime-text, ввод

Возникла проблема с компиляцией кода в редакторе Sublime Text 3. А именно: (показываю на примере калькулятора на С++) при вводе действия (по нажатию Enter) ничего не происходит, лишь курсор переносится на следующую строку.

Такая проблема присутствует при компиляции всех программ (я пробовал на Python и С++), где нужен ввод с клавиатуры.

p.s Если кому нужно: то компилятор, который я использую для С++ - это g++.

Прошу помочь решить проблему, а не просить использовать другую IDE. Всем спасибо :)

[image]

Comment: Если что, то проблема не в коде. Проверял его в других IDE - все прекрасно работает.

Comment: Так, проблему с вводом в Python я пофиксил установкой SublimeREPL.
А вот что делать с С++ - не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как мне подсказали на англоязычном StackOverflow: "Sublime не поддерживает запуск интерактивных программ, если вы не используете сторонний пакет. Это очень распространенная проблема. Для запуска таких программ можно использовать Terminus" - [автор ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814803/odatnurd).

Я решил поделиться данной информацией с этим сообществом и надеюсь, что она будет для кого-то полезна.